# Program crashes on large inputs (C)

Tags: c, crash

Please take a look at this C code. It is a small program I've written, which takes a number n as input and calculates all prime numbers from 2 to n. It works fine when n<100, but if I put in 1000 or more it crashes. I can't figure out why, since the array, in which the numbers are stored is dynamically allocated, so lack of memory shouldn't be a problem.

So, why does the program crash on large inputs?

Also, I apologize for the bad readability of the code. I'm just starting out with programming.

**code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int n;
    int *array = malloc((n-1)*sizeof array);
    int q = 0;
    int k;
    int *array2;

    printf("Geben Sie eine natuerliche Zahl n ein: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\n");

    for(i=0; i<=n-2; i++){
        array[i] = i+2;
    }

    while(q<=n-2){
        while(array[q]==0&&q<=n-2){
            q++;
        }
        for(i=q+1; i<=n-2; i++){
            if(array[i]%array[q]==0){
                array[i] = 0;
            }
        }
        q++;
    }

    PART1:
    for(i=0; array[i]!=0; i++){
        if(array[i+1]==0){
            int j;
            for(j=i+1; j<=n-2; j++){
                if(array[j]!=0){
                    array[i+1] = array[j];
                    array[j] = 0;
                    goto PART1;
                }
            }
            k = i;
            goto PART2;
        }
    }

    PART2:
    *array2 = malloc((k+1)*sizeof array2);

    for(i=0; i<=k; i++){
        array2[i]=array[i];    //Here's where the program crashes
    }

    free(array);

    for(i=0; i<k; i++){
        printf("%d ,", array2[i]);
    }

    printf("%d\n\n", array2[k]);

    free(array2);
    return 0;
}
```

codeblocks debugger says: program received signal SIGSEGV , Segmentation fault, at line 53. I marked it in the code.

Comment: What sort of crash? Have you tried a debugger to determine exactly where/how it is crashing?

Comment: use gdb to see where it is crashing and post that. one issue, is you are `allocating array based on ( an undefined n )` before you scanf for n. similarly the contents of array are undefined in your first loop..

Comment: codeblocks debugger says: program received signal SIGSEGV , Segmentation fault, at line 53. I marked it in the code. But I don't know what it means.

Comment: @amdixon I have moved the array declaration below scanf, same results

Comment: I wrote "here's where the program crashes" as a comment in the code. Unfortunately I don't know where exactly to type in bt in codeblocks debugger. I just know how to start it.

Comment: if you look at the line its crashing on, it is trying to access `array2`. then check how you allocated `array2` ( compare with array1 )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77370/discussion-between-amdixon-and-arthur).

Comment: `*array2  = ...` Um. shouldn't that be `array2 = ... `? And didn't your compiler warn you about saving `void*` to an `int` ? Or at least a "array2 used here as not been initialized" ?

Comment: Changing the code shown after answers had been given referring to the code is not a good idea, as it might render the answer ununderstandable. I just rolled back "Edit 4" therefore.

Comment: Also this `...= malloc((n-1)*sizeof array);` should be `= malloc((n-1)*sizeof *array);`, as the former version allocated space for pointers to `int` where as the latter does this for `int`s, which is what you seem to want. The same applies on the memory allocation for `array2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**process to fix**

- use a debugger ( always ) to find the line causing segfault
- study the offending variables involved

In this case, line 53 was referring to an `array2` access which was not properly allocated..

**changes required**

> - move allocation of array1 after the scanf has properly assigned n
> - change the allocation of array2 which was previously assigning malloc return to the contents of the pointer array2 instead of array2 ( which at this stage was also unallocated ) pointer
> - adjust allocation to use `sizeof(*array1+2)` as identified by @alk

**adjusted code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, n, q = 0, k, *array2;

    printf("Geben Sie eine natuerliche Zahl n ein: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int *array = malloc((n-1)*sizeof(*array));
    printf("\n");

    for(i=0; i<=n-2; i++){
        array[i] = i+2;
    }

    while(q<=n-2){
        while(array[q]==0&&q<=n-2){
            q++;
        }
        for(i=q+1; i<=n-2; i++){
            if(array[i]%array[q]==0){
                array[i] = 0;
            }
        }
        q++;
    }

    PART1:
    for(i=0; array[i]!=0; i++){
        if(array[i+1]==0){
            int j;
            for(j=i+1; j<=n-2; j++){
                if(array[j]!=0){
                    array[i+1] = array[j];
                    array[j] = 0;
                    goto PART1;
                }
            }
            k = i;
            goto PART2;
        }
    }

    PART2:
    array2 = malloc((k+1)*sizeof(*array2));

    for(i=0; i<=k; i++){
        array2[i]=array[i];    //Here's where the program crashes
    }

    free(array);

    for(i=0; i<k; i++){
        printf("%d ,", array2[i]);
    }

    printf("%d\n\n", array2[k]);

    free(array2);
    return 0;
}
```

See also this article on implementing [`sieve of erastothenes`](http://www.programminglogic.com/the-sieve-of-eratosthenes-implemented-in-c/) in c.